# validate url and check if url is domain or subdomain

Tags: javascript, validation, url

I need to validate the URL and check if URL entered is domain or subdomain.
I tried a solution, it work but in some scenario it failed.

```
function subDomain(url) 
{

    // IF THERE, REMOVE WHITE SPACE FROM BOTH ENDS
    url = url.replace(new RegExp(/^\s+/),""); // START
    url = url.replace(new RegExp(/\s+$/),""); // END

    // IF FOUND, CONVERT BACK SLASHES TO FORWARD SLASHES
    url = url.replace(new RegExp(/\\/g),"/");

    // IF THERE, REMOVES 'http://', 'https://' or 'ftp://' FROM THE START
    //url = url.replace(new RegExp(/^http\:\/\/|^https\:\/\/|^ftp\:\/\//i),"");

    // IF THERE, REMOVES 'www.' FROM THE START OF THE STRING
    url = url.replace(new RegExp(/^www\./i),"");

    // REMOVE COMPLETE STRING FROM FIRST FORWARD SLASH ON
    url = url.replace(new RegExp(/\/(.*)/),"");

    // REMOVES '.??.??' OR '.???.??' FROM END - e.g. '.CO.UK', '.COM.AU'
    if (url.match(new RegExp(/\.[a-z]{2,3}\.[a-z]{2}$/i))) {
        url = url.replace(new RegExp(/\.[a-z]{2,3}\.[a-z]{2}$/i),"");

    // REMOVES '.??' or '.???' or '.????' FROM END - e.g. '.US', '.COM', '.INFO'
    } else if (url.match(new RegExp(/\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i))) {
        url = url.replace(new RegExp(/\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i),"");
    }

    // CHECK TO SEE IF THERE IS A DOT '.' LEFT IN THE STRING
    var subDomain = (url.match(new RegExp(/\./g))) ? true : false;
    return(subDomain);
}
```

Results:

```
 
mydomain.com -> false 

subdomain.mydomain.com -> true

mydomain.com. -> true
```

Comment: What results did you expect?

Comment: I guess mydomain.com. to be false...

Comment: So he got it the first tym i guess

Comment: it should show false for " mydomain.com. " it invalid url and also not subdomain

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can actually test this in one regex, example:

```js
var isSubdomain = function(url) {
    url = url || 'http://www.test-domain.com'; // just for the example
    var regex = new RegExp(/^([a-z]+\:\/{2})?([\w-]+\.[\w-]+\.\w+)$/);

    return !!url.match(regex); // make sure it returns boolean
}

console.log(isSubdomain("example.com"));
console.log(isSubdomain("http://example.com:4000"));
console.log(isSubdomain("www.example.com:4000"));
console.log(isSubdomain("https://www.example.com"));
console.log(isSubdomain("sub.example.com"));
console.log(isSubdomain("example.co.uk")); //it doesn't work on these very specific cases
```

Comment: im no javascript expert can you add a small example using your code. thanks

Comment: i tried this and it always return null


var url = "sub.mydomain.com"

var n=url.match(/^\w+\:\/{2}(\w+\.\w+){2}$/);

alert(n);

Comment: Successfully tested my example in firebug console.

Comment: its showing true for http://www.domain.com .. its not subdomain.. it should say false. am i missing anything ?

Comment: From your example code I assumed you have `url = 'protocol://subdomain.domain.toplevel'`, not `url = 'subdomain.domain.toplevel'`

Comment: Btw: just tested my regex again, I get `false` with both `subdomain.domain.toplevel` and `domain.toplevel` (because of the protocol filter).

Comment: Updated my solution to support either `subdomain.domain.toplevel` or `protocol://subdomain.domain.toplevel`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23791/discussion-between-aaqib-iqbal-and-simon)

Comment: What if    url = domain.co.us

Comment: @niravpatel9898 such as `example.co.uk` it doesn't work

Comment: @Simon the third and last example doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1):

You can just use URI to do it.
https://medialize.github.io/URI.js/docs.html

```
const subdomain = new URI('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14644805/validate-url-and-check-if-url-is-domain-or-subdomain').subdomain()

subdomain // Will be an empty string if no subdomain exists
```

then just use it in a function

```
function isSubdomain(url) {
  return Boolean(new URI(url).subdomain())
}
```